# Sudoku layout with malloc crash

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, malloc

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

void *mymalloc(size_t size){
void *x=malloc(size);
if(x==NULL){
    printf("Not enought memory for you!\n");
 exit(1);}
else return x;
}

int main(){
int m , n , **A , i , j , z ,k;
printf("Give rows: \n");
    scanf("%d" , &n);
    printf("Enter columns: \n");
    scanf("%d" , &m);
    A=(int**)mymalloc(n*sizeof(int));
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        A[i]=(int*)mymalloc(m*sizeof(int));
    }
    printf("Give your sudoku: \n");
    for(k=0;k<m;k++){
        for(z=0;z<n;z++){
            for(i=0;i<n;i++){
                printf(" %d: " , i);
                for(j=0;j<m;j++){
                    printf("%d" , A[i][j]=j);
                }
            printf("  ");
            }
        printf("\n");
        }
    printf("  \n");
    }
}
```

When 'n' (rows) is less than 4 this programs `printf` the layout of a sudoku with 'n' rows and 'm' columns. But when rows are more than 4 the program crashes.

Comment: `A[i]` is an `int *`, but you allocate space for `A` as if it were an array of `int`.

Comment: The double indirection is pointless, since each of your rows has the same number of columns. You might as well just allocate one large array of arrays.

Comment: what's wrong with this code for n>4?

Comment: Out-of-bounds array access.

Comment: `A=(int**)mymalloc(n*sizeof(int));` --> `A = mymalloc(n * sizeof *A);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Main problem: incorrect memory allocation:   (@Kerrek SB)
`sizeof(int)` may not be the saem size as `sizeof(int*)`

```
 //  A=(int**)mymalloc(n*sizeof(int));
 A=(int**)mymalloc(n*sizeof(int*));
```

To avoid this mistake, recommend this style, less error prone and easier to maintain.

```
A = mymalloc(n * sizeof *A);
```

---

Other minor issues:

```
// printf("Not enought (spelling)
printf("Not enough ...

// int main() { // Invalid signature
int main(void) {

// No need for cast 
// A[i] = (int*) mymalloc(...   
A[i] = (int*) mymalloc(...

return 0; // missing main() return value
```